# Linear Model in R for just a particular range of index

Tags: r, regression, lm

I want to Fill in the blanks to produce a function with arguments data and ind that computes the point estimate of the regression coefficients for a subset of the original data indicated by ind. Check your function
gives the same output as mine.

```
get_regression_coefs <- function(data, ind){
fit <- lm(____ ~ ____, data = ____[____, ])
coef(____)
}

get_regression_coefs(water_qual, 1:10)
## (Intercept) population median_income prop_children LO_health
## 3.5346120939 -0.0002160563 -0.0473334873 -2.3760093672 0.3081064103
```

This is what I did, but it doesn't produce the right output.

```
get_regression_coefs <- function(data, ind){
   
   fit <- lm(data[ind,1] ~ as.matrix(data[ind,-1]), data = data[ind, ])
   coef(fit)
 }
 
 get_regression_coefs(water_qual, 1:10)


                          (Intercept)    as.matrix(data[ind, -1])population 
                         3.5346120939                         -0.0002160563 
as.matrix(data[ind, -1])median_income as.matrix(data[ind, -1])prop_children 
                        -0.0473334873                         -2.3760093672 
    as.matrix(data[ind, -1])LO_health 
                         0.3081064103
```

How do I get rid of the "as.matrix(data[ind, -1])"?
Thanks

Comment: read the coef() into an object and use stringr::str_replace() or strsplit() functions on the names().

Answer (score 0):

If it is always your first column as the dependent variable:

```
get_regression_coefs <- function(data, ind){
   
   f = reformulate(response=colnames(data)[1],termlabels=colnames(data)[-1])
   fit <- lm(f, data = data[ind, ])
   coef(fit)
 }

 get_regression_coefs(mtcars,1:20)
(Intercept)         cyl        disp          hp        drat          wt 
 9.94145647  0.15637333 -0.01101635 -0.01341279  7.15255968  0.31382129 
       qsec          vs          am        gear        carb 
-0.11599981 -2.29398779  0.08732558 -0.49188785 -2.89550650
```